# How to create a wordpress database file with existing files in my site directory?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wamp

I have a live wordpress website, due to some problem my database table become empty. Now I have only files and folders of my website. So please guide me how to create a clone of my website in my wamp server localhost with existing file/folders in root directory without database file?

Comment: you've lost data from your database? now you want to recover it?

Comment: Install wp in localhost then download all the plugin and active them from FTP, then start building your web site form scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is an excellent tool to migrate from live to local and vice versa [All in one wp migrator](http://All-in-One%20WP%20Migration%20%E2%80%94%20WordPress%20Plugins) copies all files and database. But in your case not sure if it will help . 
   To copy the files locally all you need is filezilla and the ftp credentials which may be the same as cpanel credentials. Then copy all files to local folder for website of your wamp. Php myadmin on your live site dump the sql and import into your local wamp php . 
   Can you check if you have a back up via the cpanel under softaculous installer you may be able to restore a back up of the site.

Comment: Hello arthur, I already transfered all files through filezilla, I didn't have any backup. As the database in my live site is empty, No use even if I import my database to my local server. Anyhow I have all the images in my files which I used for my website.

Comment: WordPress depends heavily on the database to define the posts and pages of your website and only the media files are saved as flat files. Was hacked once lost my entire db and had no back ups . I had to recreate the WordPress site and patch up with the images I had left now I back up religiously each site I make a change to .

Answer (score 0):

If your database is empty and there is no backup then all the contents of your website (except for photos) are lost.

Your hosting company may have made automatic backups and you ought to contact them right away.

You can make a MAMP clone using your current files and images, but none of your old content will appear and your images will not appear in the Media Manager. The images will need to be re-imported.

To make a local MAMP site with your existing files, first create a new blank Wordpress installation using the following instructions:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP

A new contentless Wordpress database will be created in this process.

Then remove all the Wordpress files *except* wp-config.php and copy all your old live site's files into the folder. When you reload Wordpress it will be running off the live site's code and plugins.